# Four wire voltage sensing, all four wires in one cable?

Tags: wire, voltage-measurement, twisted-pair

If I twist the power positive and negative wire together and do the same for the sensing wires, can all four wires (two twisted pair) be in one cable or they should be physically separated from each other?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjDYdV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Twisting the power wires as one pair, and the sense wires as another, will tend to reduce interference on the measurements. Both pairs can be in the same cable.

Comment: You can use [star quad microphone cable](https://media.rs-online.com/t_large/C209147-01.jpg).

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thanks.

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks.

Comment: @BrianDrummond, can you improve that comment into an answer, I'll upvote it.